# How to execute ASP.NET Pages on Server

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a simple asp.net page and uploaded it to the server but it is not working. Can anyone tell me about this issue, I have asked on many blogs but couldn't get the suitable answer.

Thanks,
Haider

Comment: Could you show the code? Do you get any error messages? _What_ is not working?

Comment: A suitable answer requires a suitable question.  "Uploaded"  does not adequately describe all the steps you have perform in an attempt to make the page available and "not working" does not adequately describe what problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a virtual directory in the IIS and then publish the page to that directory.
And don't forget to convert the virtual directory to an application.After this you can explore the directory and will find the pages deployed there.This can be view in Browser also.